# Touchscreen with extern power supply

Tags: power-supply, touchscreen, usb-power

So,

I have a 7 inch touchscreen from waveshare. The touchscreen works via HDMI to get the image and the power and touch function goes via usb to the pi. So the power comes from the pi...

The problem here is, I draw way too much amps from my pi when I turn the screen on... now what I want to acheve is that I can use the touchscreen as normal, but provide power to it via an extern power supply. So when I did this on the standard usb input, the touch stopped working. How can I fix this issue so I can have the touchscreen powered from an extern power supply but still have another usb cable that runs to the pi to get the touch to work?

**edit**

To make it clear, some diagrams have been added.

This is how it is NOW:
[image: First]

And this is how I want it, but I don't know if this is possible or not and how I should dot it:

[image: Finish]

Comment: Wait. In order to not power the LCD from the pi, you went from the pi's hdmi to the pi's USB?

Comment: No, I always use the hdmi to get the image on the screen, but I used the usb ports on the pi to power it, however those can't deliver enough amps... so I used an external power supply. But then the touch doesn't work anymore... that's where I'm looking for to get a solution for it.

Comment: Because you ran out of USB cables?. Also, what touchscreen is it? What LCD?, What power supply have you tried? There's a lot of information missing.

Comment: Not because I ran out of cabels... I use the official 2.5 amps power supply of raspberry pi. And the lcd touchscreen is the 7inch touchscreen from waveshare, as said in the question...

Comment: Maybe a diagram or picture of your setup would help with the confusion.

Comment: I hav updated the question with two diagrams, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen on another forum a tip, and I hope it helps: Use an externally powered USB Hub. It will supply power for both devices and the USB communication for your touchscreen.